# Alternative to "-Contains" that compares value instead of reference

Tags: powershell, boolean, comparison, equality, object-reference

I have a list of file objects, and I want to check whether a given file object appears inside that list. The `-Contains` operator is nearly what I'm looking for, but it appears that `-Contains` uses a very strict equality test where object references have to be identical. Is there some less strict alternative? I want the `$boolean`variable in the code below to return `True` the second time as well as the first time.

```
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       14.08.2017     18.33              5 file1.txt
-a----       14.08.2017     18.33              5 file2.txt


PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp> $files1 = Get-ChildItem .
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp> $files2 = Get-ChildItem .
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp> $file = $files1[1]
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp> $boolean = $files1 -Contains $file
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp> $boolean
True
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp> $boolean = $files2 -Contains $file
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp> $boolean
False
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents\temp>
```

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: Either `$files2 = $files1.Clone()` or use `Where-Object`

Comment: `[bool](Compare-Object $files2 $file -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent)`

Comment: `-Contains` use standard PowerShell equality testing: `([bigint]1) -contains '0001'`. But `FileInfo` class does not describe how to compare value.

Comment: `$Files2.FullName -contains $file.FullName`

Comment: What is it you really want to do?  Find file with same contents, same names, or other?

Comment: @KoryGill I'm making a script that monitors a directory for new file additions and automatically executes any new file that appears.

Comment: So do you need to handle delete, rename, move, locked files, etc. to ensure that you catch every situation there is?  Reason I asked is that in such case you may need to consider hashing or the like.  As for what you are doing, RoboCopy actually can provide a lot of info that may do a lot of the "heavy lifting" for you.  That's another topic altogether...

Comment: It's not that critical, but I still appreciate your suggestion. My script is designed to emulate an end-user that uncritically executes any new file that is uploaded to an FTP-server. Both this client machine and the FTP-server is in an isolated lab outside of production and will only be handled by people who know what they're doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` returns objects of the type `[System.IO.FileInfo]`.

```
Get-ChildItem  C:\temp\test\2.txt | Get-Member | Select-Object TypeName -Unique

TypeName
--------
System.IO.FileInfo
```

As PetSerAl mentioned in the comments `[System.IO.FileInfo]` does not implement IComparable or IEquatable.

```
[System.IO.FileInfo].GetInterfaces()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ISerializable
```

Without these, as you noticed PowerShell will only support reference equality. Lee Holmes' has a great [blog post on this](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/12/05/powershells-eq-operator-reference-equality-vs-value-equality/).

The solution to this is then to make comparisons on sub-properties that are comparable. You can choose a specific property that would be unique, like `Fullname` as Mathias R Jessen mentioned. With the drawback that if the other properties are different, they will not be evaluated.

```
'a' | Out-File .\file1.txt
$files = Get-ChildItem .
'b' | Out-File .\file1.txt
$file = Get-ChildItem .\file1.txt
$files.fullname -Contains $file.fullname

True
```

Alternatively, you could use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet which will compare all of the properties between the two objects (or the specific properties you choose with `-Property`).

Using the `-IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent` flags of `Compare-Object`, we can find all the objects with matching properties. Then when an array is cast to a `[bool]`, if it is non-empty it will be `$True` and if empty it will be `$False`.

```
'a' | Out-File .\file1.txt
$files = Get-ChildItem .
$file = Get-ChildItem .\file1.txt
[bool](Compare-Object $files $file -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent)

True


'a' | Out-File .\file1.txt
$files = Get-ChildItem .
'b' | Out-File .\file1.txt
$file = Get-ChildItem .\file1.txt
[bool](Compare-Object $files $file -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent)

False
```

`Compare-Object` can be resource intensive, so it's best to use other forms of comparison when possible.

Comment: In my particular case, both of these solutions are suitable. Thank you!